# Суммирование значений в столбце по нескольким условиям

Tags: excel

Есть массив данных, нужно найти значение.

Строка определяется сцепкой столбцов `B` и `C` (столбец `А` в примере), а столбец через `ГПР` (количество столбцов может меняться, поэтому `ГПР`). Получается значение 3 в примере.

А если таких значений нужно получить 2 или 3 и суммировать их? В примере должно получиться 6.

Насколько понял можно тут только скрин приложить:
[image: скрин]

Comment: VBA-функция не устроит?

Comment: Хотелось бы чтобы было попроще, вба я потом самостоятельно не смогу поправить если что)

Comment: *вба я потом самостоятельно не смогу поправить если что* "Если что" - это что именно? Если заранее нормально продумать, что действительно нужно - так потом и править не придётся... да и освоение VBA в минимальном объёме для простейших корректировок - не такая уж и сложная задача.

Comment: Так вот знать бы все "если что" заранее) а то как решит кто-то где-то, что теперь будет так и все сломалось)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ИНДЕКС`'ом определяем диапазон нужного столбца и суммируем по условию:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(A2:A7;"11";ИНДЕКС(D2:J7;;ПОИСКПОЗ("ост";D1:J1;)))
```

Без доп. столбца:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--(B2:B7=1);--(C2:C7=1);ИНДЕКС(D2:J7;;ПОИСКПОЗ("ост";D1:J1;)))
```

Вторая формула медленнее, но если таких всего несколько, то замедление в какие-то наносекунды не должно напрягать :)

Закрепить ссылки, если ужно.

Если критерии поиска вынести в отдельные ячейки, формула будет гибче.

Кстати, так же можно суммировать значения искомой строки при повторяющихся значениях в шапке таблицы:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(D1:J1;"ост";ИНДЕКС(D2:J7;ПОИСКПОЗ("11";A2:A7;);))
```

Comment: В примере работает, буду пробовать в оригинале, спасибо)